# how to using jq command to Delete the specified multi-line field

Tags: docker, jq

I want to use the jq command to filter out the architecture I want in the manifest file of docker

```
cat manifest.json |jq -r
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json",
  "manifests": [
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "size": 1785,
      "digest": "sha256:34860ea294a018d392e61936f19a7862d5e92039d196cac9176da14b2bbd0fe3",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "amd64",
        "os": "linux"
      }
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "size": 1996,
      "digest": "sha256:93d5f2293f6faf76fc3f2ff30628cf2100b68e3cf16901f39f01d449e67f67d9",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "arm",
        "os": "linux"
      }
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "size": 1996,
      "digest": "sha256:a0000b627744766025f552c4db171a00b055d5d709f22aec8be96b6375b220cf",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "arm64",
        "os": "linux"
      }
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "size": 1995,
      "digest": "sha256:227c06dc0468dacfcfc04cc0aad3f5138a51bb2afa4d8252c6e83ca39beb8c6f",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "ppc64le",
        "os": "linux"
      }
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "size": 1996,
      "digest": "sha256:e7cfbfe13f7a179277f55a835abc0b01f9c6c21892c1ae1b0007f2e09777bca0",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "s390x",
        "os": "linux"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```
cat manifest.json |jq -r 'del(.manifests[] |select(.platform.architecture=="arm" and .platform.architecture=="ppc64le"))'
```

The above command does not take effect. If I only want to keep the amd64 and arm64 architectures in the manifest file, how should I write this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `or` instead of `and` since a field can only have one of those options (if at all), never both.

According to "I only want to keep the amd64 and arm64 architectures",  instead of deleting you can simply go the keeping route:

```sh
jq '
  .manifests |= map(select(
    .platform.architecture == "arm64" or .platform.architecture == "amd64"
  ))
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/CIIXK0gyS2)

If you're using jq 1.6 or later, you can simplify this using the `IN` filter:

```sh
jq '
  .manifests |= map(select(
    IN(.platform.architecture; "arm64", "amd64")
  ))
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/VmUBUcXkHh)

Output

```json
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json",
  "manifests": [
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "size": 1785,
      "digest": "sha256:34860ea294a018d392e61936f19a7862d5e92039d196cac9176da14b2bbd0fe3",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "amd64",
        "os": "linux"
      }
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "size": 1996,
      "digest": "sha256:a0000b627744766025f552c4db171a00b055d5d709f22aec8be96b6375b220cf",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "arm64",
        "os": "linux"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```